# Hanban/HSK Official Website Resources Download

Tags: resources, hsk

Does anybody know where to find the most recent HSK test materials, especially the **vocabulary lists** to download?

I have checked the [official site](http://www.hanban.org/tests/node_7486.htm), but the 资料下载 'button' doesn't work

---

UPDATE: Found it.

All the downloads (audio samples, .PDFs, [vocab list](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/HSK-2012.xls)) are on a different domain: [http://www.chinesetest.cn](http://www.chinesetest.cn/godownload.do)

UPDATE2: Actually there used to be a PDF which contained the corresponding pinyins, not only the words/characters themselves. Does anybody know where could that file be found?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the bottom for PDFs, latest tests, vocabulary lists and pretty much everything to do with HSK.
http://www.chinaeducenter.com/en/exams.php

(this is in response to the below)

UPDATE2: Actually there used to be a PDF which contained the corresponding pinyins, not only the words/characters themselves. Does anybody know where could that file be found?

Answer (score 0):

The place where you can download materials is [ChineseTest.cn](http://www.chinesetest.cn/godownload.do), but the [Hanban website](http://english.hanban.org/node_8002.htm) currently sends you to the non-existing www.chinesetesting.cn site to download mock tests ...

Since part of the question is about vocabulary lists with pinyin, here is [the best list I have found](http://www.mandarinchineseschool.com/files/HSK/New_HSK_Level_IV_Vocabulary.pdf): this PDF file contains the vocabulary for HSK4 in a long table with columns for the following types of content: the word's number, the word itself, pinyin transcription, part of speech (verb, noun, ...), meaning (i.e. English translation) and an *example sentence* (!). (If you are only interested in HSK3, you can ignore the last 600 words in the table.)

If you want even more HSK-related materials, check the [HSK section](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/chinese/index.html) on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can download HSK materials here:
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/download/pdf

Answer (score 0):

To share, the HSK Locker app has all the official words and phrases listed as per the HSK lvl 1-6 exams. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.hsklocker)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the 资料下载 is a title only; those below the title are the actual links

Comment: Confusingly, that red thingy looks like a button to me.

Comment: They made mouse-over event on it which trick you into thinking it's a button.  It's "drawing snake with legs" and I am sure you know what i mean hah

Comment: Yes, 画蛇加足. I guess this was the first chengyu I had ever heard.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster The proper usage should be `画蛇添足`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Good, I was wondering why 加 felt so odd, I googled it and confusingly enough some people seem to use it with 加.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster It must be so-called `以讹传讹`. :)